# I need regex which avoids all zeros

Tags: regex

I need one regex  which avoid all the zeros including hypen also. Below is the pattern

000-000-0000

I want to avoid the above number to enter, other than that any form of combination is ok.

Example

001-000-0000
000-008-0000
000-000-5000

Comment: how about a conditional? `if (x=="000-000-0000") puts "Invalid input"`

Comment: your question is not clear.  Please give exact inputs and outputs required.  Does the "001-000-0000" give "1" or "001" or "001-000-0000" for example?

Comment: `if (number.match(yourRegex) && number != "000-000-0000") then (ok()) else (ko())`?

Comment: I don't think a regex is what you really need here.

Comment: "I need regex ..." is a bad way to start a question on SO. See [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: My question is simple. If an end-user tries to enter the value for Phone number with zeros only then i want to restrict him. An user can't enter the number as 000-000-0000. A user can enter any kind 001-000-0000 or 000-009-0000 or 000-000-8888 is ok. using Regex only i need solution

Comment: Try something first, also "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.".

Comment: Can anyone give me the solution for my query. Im using mvc3 in asp.net application

Answer (score 0):

Here i got myself the solution for my query.

The regex which avoid the 000-000-0000 pattern is below

"^(?![0]{3}[-]{1}[0]{3}[-]{1}[0]{4}).*$"

Thanks